# Is there a way to apply something like pagination to query results in QuestDB?

Tags: node.js, questdb

I have many large tables in Questdb and I am testing returning the results in a node application using the example:

```js
const all = await client.query("SELECT x FROM mytable;")
console.log(all.rows)
// can get all for this column
```

I would like to have something similar to pagination, where I want to return, display and make calculations on batches of results, so for example, let's say the batch or pagination size is 1000:

- most recent 1000 rows
- next batch of 1000 rows
- etc. ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `LIMIT` keyword:

```js
const first = await client.query("SELECT x FROM mytable LIMIT 1000;")
```

A second batch can be fetched with a range:

```js
const second = await client.query("SELECT x FROM mytable LIMIT 1000, 2000;")
```

If the dataset is static, this might be okay, but be careful if the dataset is dynamic and new records are incoming in the time between your initial query and the query with a range might have an undesired offset. In this case, there may be a more efficient way such as fetching a larger batch in one go and paginating client-side as JSON or similar.

There are other examples in the QuestDB [documentation for LIMIT](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/limit#examples).